# Saving Vault secrets in Consul

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

Tell me please, how can I do next?:

1. I am creating a secret in Vault.
2. This secret is automatically added to Consul.
3. I go to Consul and see the keys from Vault there.

Please give me documentation or article.

Comment: you're using consul as vault storage backend? then you can't access through consul, you need access the secret from vault, as consul just act as storage for vault

Comment: @gumelaragum thank you for help. Yes, I use but when I look for secret in Consul (in vault directory) I see data like "X�޵'�EM'�,i��%E�UR�"�>�1" and I don't understand what can I do with this. Could you tall me what can I do or give any good article about this?

Comment: its encrypted data by vault, and store it in consul kv storage

Comment: @gumelaragum is completely correct. Please elaborate on why you are trying to access Vault through Consul instead of Vault.

Comment: consul act as service discovery, an app that connect to consul using consul client can get vault address by accessing `active.vault.service.consul` from your app that integrated with consul
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/consul
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/ha-with-consul

hashicorp right now recommended to use raft storage backend instead of consul storage backend, and I don't use consul as storage backend tho...

Comment: @MattSchuchard We had config file in web application (ASP.Net core) and decided to use consul instead  config file but my colleague like to storage  config data in Vault and get those data throw Consul. Thank vary much for you help

Comment: You would then need to explain to your colleague that you cannot access Vault through Consul as that would be a major security hole.

Comment: @gumelaragum Wow, thank you for those articles and your  clarifying.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'll show him your comments and this will help us.